# What is this sound that can be heard in Swedish?

Tags: phonology, swedish

There seems to be a special L sound in Swedish, I've tried to find what consonant/vowel it is for a long time, but eventually I decided to ask here

Two videos with the sound in it:
[Video 1, at 3:19, the word "filen"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQx3ACpbXhk)
[Video 2, 0:57~0:58, 1:07~1:08, and many others](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRWc0Tk_M0Y)

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like a normal L, except for those that sound like a hybrid of L and R,and this sound is known as the retroflex flap https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroflex_flap - and it appears in some dialects of Swedish

Comment: @Vijejoslagc I don't think its the "L" thats special I think its the "I" before the "L". Listen to the word "fint" and tell us if you hear the same sound you are referring to: http://forvo.com/search/fint/sv

Comment: Seems like it really is the I before L.

Comment: Sounds like a dental /l/, ie [ l̺ ].

Answer (score 1):

In the first video, the sound is simply /l/, spelled  in Swedish. This is the same as L in German or French.

The timecodes in the second video all lack L so I'm assuming you mean R. In this case I'm analyzing it as /[ɹ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_and_postalveolar_approximants)/ but it's most commonly analyzed as /[ɾ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental,_alveolar_and_postalveolar_flaps)/. Depending on the dialect or person, it can also be pronounced /r/ or /ʀ/.

As Luboš mentioned in the comments, L in some dialects is also /ɽ/. This is however not the case in either of these videos as they are both in Central Standard Swedish.